# What is md5_hash property of BlobInfo object intended for?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

If I call

```
blobsotre.BlobInfo.properties()
```

the function return

```
set(['filename', 'creation', 'content_type', 'md5_hash', 'size'])
```

but if I call

```
a = blobstore.BlobInfo.all()
obj = a.fetch(1)[0]
print obj.md5_hash
```

the function raise exception

```
AttributeError(name) AttributeError: md5_hash
```

What is md5_hash property of BlobInfo object intended for?
P.S. I want to check what uploaded file is not exist into Blobstore.

Comment: By the way, `obj = a.fetch(1)[0]` is just a particularly convoluted and error-prone alternative to `obj = a.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

A cryptographic hash function can be used for many things:

- to provide an integrity check value for the file/blob to detect changes
- to provide a unique identifier for a file/blob used to refer to the contents
- to enable fast lookup of the contents of a hash table
- to enable fast searching for duplicate files
- etc

The "intended" use of course depends on what application the blobstore is supporting - are you building a shopping cart, or a data cache, or a map-reduce processing application, or what?

Comment: I know purpose of hash. I asked about intended of md5_hash property in BlobInfo object. The property exist, but not documented, and remain empty after I upload file in Blobstore.

Comment: The automagically generated java documentation for BlobInfoFactory says "BlobInfo metadata is stored in read-only __BlobInfo__ entities in the datastore. This class provides an easy way to access these entities."  Since all the metadata (content_type, creation, filename, kind, md5_hash, and size) is read-only, if after a file is loaded all the metadata except md5_hash is populated correctly, it would seem to be an error.  Do you get the same exception with `print obj.size`?

Comment: The all properties except 'md5_hash' from set(['filename', 'creation', 'content_type', 'md5_hash', 'size']) hash filled and print obj.size performed correctly. It may be a function that should fill the 'md5_hash' property has not been implemented yet? To send a file, I use the experimental file-like API.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show works fine for me, on [shell.appspot.com](http://shell.appspot.com/):

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
>>> blobstore.BlobInfo.properties()
set(['filename', 'creation', 'content_type', 'md5_hash', 'size'])
>>> o = blobstore.BlobInfo.all().get()
>>> o.md5_hash
u'5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592'
```

You must be doing something different to what's in your sample code. Can you paste your exact code, and the complete stacktrace?

Comment: It's not the code, it's something in your dev environment. What version of Python and the GAE SDK are you using? Can you import hashlib and generate an MD5 in isolation?

Comment: I used GAE 1.6.0 and Ubuntu 10.04 with python 2.6.5 by default. You say what my problem in my dev environment. I have set up virtualenv with python 2.5.6, but the problem is not disappeared. Hashlib successfully imported and I can generate MD5 hash.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have BlobInfo objects that don't have an md5_hash written including the first result returned by `blobstore.BlobInfo.all()`

You can check easily in your dev server's interactive console:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

query1 = blobstore.BlobInfo.all()
query2 = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE md5_hash != ''")

print query1.count(), query2.count()
# for me this returns '100 85'
```